# Use Python-docx to read the Word document but some texts are missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I'm using the docx package to read a Word document in Chinese and English, but when I print the text, I found some words in a paragraph and some paragraphs are missing.

**For example:**

origin text: 这是个好天气AA_BB_RRM_CC

printed text: 这是个好天气AA_BB__CC

strangly the **RRM** part is missing

btw, the missing paragraph looks the same as others

my code is following, does anybody have the same problem?

```
file = docx.Document(filename)

for para in file.paragraphs:

    content = para.text

    print(content)
```

Comment: Everything works fine on my end.